# How to split large xml files with overlaping data

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a large XML file (>10GB) which I need to split into smaller files, by applying some logic to each individual element. The same element can end up in multiple files, and not all elements will be part of the output (some elements are not needed at all).

I am using lxml for the rest of the login in the project, and do rely on many of the features.

For example:

input.xml

```xml
<root>
    <parent>
        <child_a>
            ...
        </child_a>
        <child_b>
            ...
        </child_b>
        <common>
            ...
        </common>
        <partially_common>
            <just_a>
                ...
            </just_a>
            <just_b>
                ...
            </just_b>
            <both>
                ...
            </both>
        </partially_common>        
        <unneeded>
            ...
        </unneeded>
    </parent>
</root>
```

output_a.xml

```xml
<root>
    <parent>
        <child_a>
            ...
        </child_a>
        <common>
            ...
        </common>
        <partially_common>
            <just_a>
                ...
            </just_a>
            <both>
                ...
            </both>
        </partially_common>  
    </parent>
</root>
```

output_b.xml

```xml
<root>
    <parent>
        <child_b>
            ...
        </child_b>
        <common>
            ...
        </common>
        <partially_common>
            <just_b>
                ...
            </just_b>
            <both>
                ...
            </both>
        </partially_common>  
    </parent>
</root>
```

What have I tried:

1. I have managed to achieve the desired result using elementtree instead of lxml, which does offer the option for one element to be present in multiple trees. The problem is I am using lxml for the rest of the project, and I have an lxml tree when I reach this point. I do not know if it is possible to 'cast' an lxml element to elementtree element and vice-versa to achieve this result
2. I can create a new tree and use copy.deepcopy() to copy the elements. There are several problems with this approach. First, the elements tend to be large, which makes the process slower and demands more memory, which, for some files sizes, is more than is available. Second problem is that I need to update the common elements with meta information as I add it to different output files / trees, which means that I need to keep track of each copy, and perform the same action multiple times.
3. I have managed to partially make it work using trees with placeholder elements, making my updates in the input tree, and then replacing the elements before writing the files. I say partially because I am not sure how to handle nested cases, and how to make sure that all the nested placeholders are replaced

Note: It is not particularly relevant how the tree is build or managed, as long as the resulting written files are correct. Meaning, whether its multiple trees, one for each file, or a single common tree, and then conditionally writing it to files, or whether the files are written in parallel or sequentially. As long as it does not explode in terms of both time and memory.

Edit1: I do not strictly need a solution using lxml, as long as it is, in a sense, compatible

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved with a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation. (But disclaimer: there's only one streaming XSLT 3.0 processor readily available, and it's my company's product).

The basic way in which you produce two output streams from one input stream in XSLT 3.0 is shown in an example in the spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#splitting-examples. Adapted to your use case, it's something like:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:fork>
    <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:result-document href="1.xml">
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="mode1"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:sequence>
    <xsl:sequence>
      <xsl:result-document href="2.xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="mode2"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:sequence>
  </xsl:fork>
</xsl:template>
```

And then template rules for the two modes that copy everything except the elements you don't want:

```
<xsl:mode name="mode1" on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode2" on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="child-b|just_b" mode="mode1"/>
<xsl:template match="child-a|just_a" mode="mode2"/>
```

Comment: I think it should be `<xsl:template match="/">` instead of `<xsl:template match="parent">` as the shown, wanted result structure for the split documents includes the whole document structure like the root element and the parent element.